# What is ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs?

I understood ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs has three of List Collection.

```
public ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs(List<ARTrackedImage> added, List<ARTrackedImage> updated, List<ARTrackedImage> removed);
```

But I don't understand when they Add() each List collection.

what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

From time to time you should look into the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@2.1/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs.html) ;)

Basically it is exactly what you would expect from the given names:

> **`added`**: The list of ARTrackedImages added **since the last event**
>
> **`updated`**: The list of ARTrackedImages updated **since the last event**
>
> **`removed`**: The list of ARTrackedImages removed **since the last event**

"They add" these lists whenever the [`ARTracked​Image​Manager.trackedImagesChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@2.1/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARTrackedImageManager.html#UnityEngine_XR_ARFoundation_ARTrackedImageManager_trackedImagesChanged) event is invoked. It is

> **Invoked once per frame** with information about the `ARTrackedImages` that have changed, i.e., been added, updated, or removed. This happens **just before `ARTrackedImages` are destroyed**, so you can set `ARTrackedImage.destroyOnRemoval` to false from this event to suppress this behavior.